# Est-il correct de mettre deux verbes d'une phrase au subjonctif?

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, subjonctif, concordance-des-temps

Est-ce que la phrase suivante, où les deux verbes sont conjugués au subjonctif imparfait, est grammaticalement correcte: "Bien qu'il fallût que tu le tuasses"?

Answer (score 6):

Oui évidemment pour la question dans le titre mais...
**La phrase prise en exemple dans l'OP est rigoureusement incorrecte!**

Je ne suis certes pas un grand fan du subjonctif imparfait mais encore moins porté à interdire quoi que ce soit dans l'usage d'une langue.

En revanche, il me semble logique que qui veut se conformer à une règle qui commanderait l'usage d'un subjonctif, ***doit*** impérativement respecter les autres.

La première règle qui importe dans l'enchainement des propositions est, quel que soit le mode, celle de la concordance des temps.
Elle offre en plus le mérite d'une certaine logique.

Or, la concordance des temps quand on fait usage d'un subjonctif imparfait dans une subordonnée **impose** l'usage du **conditionnel passé de deuxième forme** (1)  dans la proposition précédente.

=> si ça vous amuse :

*Bien qu'il eût fallu que tu le tuasses.*

---

(1) Nota : La conjugaison du conditionnel passé de deuxième forme est identique à celle du subjonctif **plus que parfait**.

---

<sup>NDaCOSwt : Pour info :Vialatte est mort, nul besoin de chercher [sa mort prématurée](http://chasseautresor-ng.0707a.net/forum/index.php?topic=63.msg452#msg452) .</sup>